# Rails 3 render partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My setup: Rails 3.0.9, Ruby 1.9.2, jQuery 1.6.2

I'm making an AJAX call from jQuery to my Rails app to this controller

```
class ProjectsController

 def data
  @project = ....
   respond_to do |format|
   format.html
  end
 end
end
```

For the `data` action, I need to render a partial file in the `views\projects\_property.html.erb`. What's the syntax for `format.html`? I tried a variety of ways but couldn't find the right syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For ajax:

```
def data
 @project = ....
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
 end
```

And in data.js.erb

```
$("#your_id").html("<%= escape_javascript( render :partial => 'property' )%>");
```

Comment: Huh, that didn't work, it still reports missing partial. Also, does this do the same thing as your code? `format.js  { render :partial => 'property' }`, this won't require `data.js.erb` file.

Comment: is the partial in the view/projects folder?